# Claim Status Identifiers

Tags: status, dependent-claim

Does a dependent claim's status identifier change to "Currently amended" if amending only the independent claims from which it depends? The dependent claim is not amended.  Examiner is suggesting that I change the status identifier despite no changes to dependent claim (only related independent claim).

Comment: Have you changed the dependent claim number ??

Comment: Does it matter? I haven't seen it handled that way, but I don't think it's a hill worth dying on.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change status identifiers if any of the independent or dependent claims is unchanged. Status identifiers are needed to be changed in case of amendments (strikethrough of text, insertion of text, or dependency change) only.